# xmpp server and ruby on rails integration recommendations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, xmpp

**Trying to build a simple 1-1 with XMPP protocol like on facebook ( offline, online and 1-1 with buddy list )**

There are several xmpp ruby library's available on github but its not a easy choose between them, every xmpp rails solution I looked at is outdated.

A few questions:

1. Is xmpp for ruby on rails the way to go for building a facebook like 1-1 IM? ( have looked in websockets privatepub, juggernaut(rip)) all lack somewhere, nothing seems to beat the XMPP protocol
2. Whats the best XMPP gem for connecting rails with XMPP server @ 2012? many of them seem outdated, is there any project that is in use -now- and is not updated for a while but is solid enough to use on a project?

Comment: How did you solved this?

Comment: not yet any recommendations are still welcome, seems that xmpp with rails is pain but there are some projects out there that deliver rails and xmpp

Comment: I am thinking in using node.js (and NowJs) together with rails. What do you think?

Comment: I don´t need to support Internet Explorer. My chat have to run on a iOS app (mobile Safari)

Comment: I don´t want to use juggernaut. I am planning to start node server like this http://www.perfectline.ee/blog/optimizing-ruby-on-rails-application-with-nodejs or using two applications communicating with each other. What do you think?

Comment: Not sure although node.js could be a way to go yes. Would like to see a proof of concept instead of spending hours creating something from scratch ( although admitting that IS fun ) Now looking at some blogposts on open fire + xm4 and rails but haven't found anything useful yet.

Comment: http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/sparkweb/  Perhaps you can ask a question on this here on stack overflow I have already posted several questions regarding 1-1 IM in the past on the several technology I came across but went stuck due to several reasons like non supporting internet explorer ( web sockets, juggernaut)

Comment: http://community.igniterealtime.org/docs/DOC-2109 demo on the page does not seem to work, cannot create account to login.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After long digging I found a good solution to fix this:

- ejabberd xmpp server light memory and full feature set
- rails 3  + strophe and ember.js ( or another framework but strophe is xmpp client in JS)

This seems a full solution now only you have to write the client yourself

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, there is no easy way to integrate Rails with XMPP server. 
You may try https://github.com/maccman/juggernaut for chat/im.

Answer (score 2):

Faik, take a on Alex post here: http://blog.alexmaccaw.com/killing-a-library.
He describes how you can use HTML5 Server-Sent Events with ruby server-side to do same as expected with the se of XMPP.

Answer (score 1):

Try this ruby library: http://home.gna.org/xmpp4r/ It provides full XMPP protocol support.

It lists [ActionMessenger](http://trypticon.org/software/actionmessenger/) in its related projects as a rails convenience framework like ActionMailer.

Comment: very old projects.. I presume to go with a strophe js client and do that xmpp stuff in there although its client side

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution to build a xmpp chat in ruby on rails
The below link will help you to build a chat application

**xmpp4r** is the ruby on rails library to communicate with jabber server. through ruby on rails.

- http://xmpp4r.github.io/
- https://github.com/lnussbaum/xmpp4r

Answer (score 0):

I have recently implemented xmpp chat in ruby on rails server as REST
API and client as mobile App for that I have used ejabberd as xmpp server.
I have used Ejabberd ModRest module for(Register/update/Delete/Add-buddy/Remove- buddy) and all admin related tasks. I don't found any updated rails gem for that.